# Set option 'Color' not working in google apps script? (pie chart builder)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pie-chart

Thank you for reading my question. I have been successfully using a script to create pie charts. However, yesterday the code to set pie chart slices' colors, `setOption('colors',....)`, seemed to have stopped working. I have checked a few different types of code to fix it, but I am not able to fix anything related to it. I was wondering if its possible there is a change in the code and it can't be used this way any more? Please find below the code snippet as well as the link to the google sheet that has dummy data etc. Please do let me know how I can fix this? I'm a novice when it comes to coding so I'm a bit lost.

```
    function createPieChart() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var chartDataRange = sheet.getRange('G2:H5');   
  var color1 = sheet.getRange('K9').getValue();
  var color2 = sheet.getRange('K10').getValue();
  var color3 = sheet.getRange('K11').getValue();

  var pieChartBuilder = sheet.newChart()
     .addRange(chartDataRange)
     .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.PIE)
     .setPosition(2,1,0,0)
     .setOption('width',500).setOption('height',300)
     .setOption('pieHole',0.5)
     .setOption('colors', [color1,color2,color3])
     .build();
  
    sheet.insertChart(pieChartBuilder);
 }
```

Sheet Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tPc0KU2uYuN4rO32tW-s6lql_IW57kbDUdSR8ZSkVXY/edit#gid=0

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `However, yesterday the code to set pie chart slices' colors, setOption('colors',....), seemed to have stopped working.`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Comment: basically what I mean is that this code was working until yesterday. Now if I used this code, the colors of the slices do not change according to what has been set in the code.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand about your situation. In the current stage, I cannot find the change of this specification yet. I apologize for this. So, from `this code was working until yesterday.`, I thought that this might be the temporal situation. So how about waiting a little? On the other hand, when I found the change of specification, I would like to tell you.

Comment: has it been solved to you? have you noticed any modification from when it was working?

Comment: Hi Kessy, No this has not yet been fixed for me, there have been no changes in the code from when it was working and now when it is not working. I think it is an issue with the Apps Script on Google's side, perhaps it isn't able to read the script or something, unsure

Comment: @Tanaike thank you for checking anyways! Look forward if you find anything:)

Answer (score 1):

You can report it on Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191640%20status:open) so they can take a look at it.

I have found a similar issue regarding charts with Apps Script, on this issue is about the option `visibleInLegend`. You can use it as  reference to create your one or you can add to that issue: [Chart option `visibleInLegend` not working on Apps Script](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179999768)